# ElasticSearch dynamic key/value mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

Most of our data is stored in simple key/value across our platforms.

We're trying to map dynamic keys (they have a limited size).

I searched the other questions but none of the answers actually answer this simple question.

Something simple like this should work

```
        answers: {
            properties: {
                fillInText: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                comment: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                question: {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            }
        }
```

But it is indexing the childrens values :-/ (you can see comment here twice, potential index crash)

```
"answers": {
          "properties": {
            "comment": {
              "enabled": false,
              "type": "object"
            },
            "fillInText": {
              "enabled": false,
              "type": "object"
            },
            "do_you_like_cars": {
              "properties": {
                "comment": {
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  },
                  "type": "text"
                },
```

Really what we need is something simple like this, but I can't find any docs on it.

```
        answers: {
            properties: {
                "*": {
                    properties: {
                        fillInText: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                        comment: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                        question: {
                            enabled: false,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) with [`path_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) should help here. You can define your mapping like this:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "fillInText": {
          "path_match": "answers.*.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "object",
            "enabled": false
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You should, however, pay attention to the fact that this might cause [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings) because you could potentially create an unbounded number of fields inside `answers`.

Comment: thank you, I'm aware of the mapping explosion, the keys are limited to 200ish so it won't be a problem.

Comment: I guess the "fillInText" is ignored on the list? (which is fine)

Comment: It's just a name to identify the rule, you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: anything we can do with this spefically? (the name) I'm curious.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. That's free text and just helps you identify your rule names